# cURL cannot get final url

Tags: curl

When you go to url: https://vimeo.com/490405479

You are automatically redirected to https://vimeo.com/490405479/df8f45be38.

I am trying to get this redirected url using cURL, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how to fix this?

This is my code so far

```
private function getFinalURL(string $url): string
{
        $location = $url;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (preg_match('~Location: (.*)~i', $result, $match)) {
            $location = trim($match[1]);
        }

        return $location;
}
```

Comment: when i open `https://vimeo.com/490405479` i just get a HTTP 404 ```Sorry, we couldn’t find that page
Make sure you’ve typed the URL correctly, or try searching Vimeo. You could also watch one of the videos below instead.``` - perhaps its a region-locked video? or perhaps its only viewable to logged-in-people? or something? idk

Comment: @hanshenrik if you try to put the URL in your search bar, you can see that it redirects you to https://vimeo.com/490405479/df8f45be38 - how do I get this new redirected url?

Comment: run `curl 'https://vimeo.com/490405479' --dump-header - -s 2>&1 | head -1` , what do you get?

Comment: @hanshenrik 404 not found

Comment: ok open stackoverflow.com in an `incognito window` (chrome-based browsers) or `private window` (firefox) then go to `https://vimeo.com/490405479` in that window, what page do you get?

Comment: aha I see.. but how come it works in non-incognito then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235508/discussion-between-hanshenrik-and-mathias-lund).

Answer (score 0):

how do you know that the Location header points to the *final* url?
what if a.com says `Location: b.com` and b.com says `Location: c.com` and c.com says `Location: F.com` and only f.com is the final url? to find the final url, you have to follow the redirects until there's no more redirects. you can use libcurl's CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow the urls, and use CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL to find the final url, like

```
function final_url(string $url):string{
    // TODO: use CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION instead of CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
    // to minimize RAM usage.
    $ch=curl_init();
    if(!curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1
    ))){
    // error detection
    }
    curl_exec($ch);
    $ret = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment - unfortunately this code returns the original url: https://vimeo.com/490405479 :)